# R ggline: change position x axis for overlapping errorbars

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, errorbar

I'm trying to create some line graphs displaying mean and SD as well as individual datapoints for different groups and timepoints, basically like here https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggline.html

The problem is, that the  errorbars overlap and it is difficult to read them out. Therefore I would like to change the position a bit, so that they are presented next to each other.

However, adding position = position_dodge(0.3) did not affect the graph at all, regardless if I put it into the overarching ggline command or in the add.params command...

Any idea how to solve this would be appreciated!

Thank you very much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZpa8.png)

Comment: Would it not be better to facet the plot rather than making the graphical representation of your data inaccurate? Also, the x axis appears to be categorical, since it is not proportionately spaced (0.5 to 1 is the same size as 1 to 2), so adding lines probably isn't meaningful here in the first place.

Comment: how would you facet the plot?

the lines do make sense as in my case (not the example) it is an ordinal scale. But even with categorical variables, this is would be the classic interaction plot. 

I don't aim to make the presentation inaccurate, but visible. position_dodge works for many other graphical functions, but not with ggline. So I am looking for solutions.

Comment: It's really difficult to offer any concrete help to anyone on Stack Overflow when they post a question without the data and the code they used, but you can probably facet your example by adding `facet.by = "supp"` to your call. The other option is to use `ggplot` itself. The `ggline` function is just a wrapper around `ggplot` which makes it easier but gives less flexibility.

Comment: Just change "dose" to a factor and use `position = position_dodge(0.3)`.